# recursive func to find prime factors

Tags: c, recursion

i made a recursive function to find the prime factors of a number but it has a bug which makes turbo c quit. please help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int prime(int num);
int primefactor(int num,int i);
void main(void)
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number whose prime factors are to be calculated:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    primefactor(num,i);
     i=num 
    getch();
}
int primefactor(int num,int i)
{
    if(i==2)
    return 1;
    if(num%i==0)
    {
        if(prime(num))
        {
            printf(",%d",num);
            num=num/i;
            i++;
        }


    }
    i--;
    primefactor(num,i);
    return 0;
}
int prime(int num)
{
    int i,flag;
    for(i=2;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
    flag=0;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: _Turbo C?_  As in, the 1980s-era C compiler?

Comment: On what line is the compiler reporting problems and/or crashing?  You have given no information which might be useful for people to help resolve your problems.

Comment: borland turbo c 3 something ..i dont get why i am being taught it in the university :(

Comment: You need to set flag = 1 in `prime`, and return it at the end.  Or, better, when you find a factor, return 0; if you drop off the end of the loop, return 1.  Note that you really only need to go as far as the square root of num to look for factors.  This doesn't matter much when you've only fewer than 10 digits in the number, but it really does matter if you have many more digits.

Comment: @James: Turbo C was very much in action in academic world till at least 2003 :)

Comment: @Techie: As part of syllabus? I don't think so unless you got computers/software donated by seniors :).

Comment: @fahad: has to be a int main( (assumesTurbo C Windows)

@Praveen: Windows is still prevalent in education institutes. At least in India. Primarily due to *resistance* in teachers to move on to Linux. VC is/was expensive for some. May be its too slow on the slower machines that still persist. So Turbo C still holds good in there. Maybe not anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(little too sleepy to write good code.. so am sorry in advance for any bugs :p )

a simpler non recursive version

```
printPrimeFactors(int num) {

  for (i = 2; i < sqrt(num); i=getNextPrime()) {
     if (num %i)
        printf("%d", i);
  } 

}
```

if you have to use recursion

```
void factorization(int x, int i=2)
{
   if(x==1)
    return;

   if(x%i==0&&isPrime(i))
   {
    printf("%d ",i);
    factorization(x/i,i);
   }
   else
    factorization(x,i+1);


}
```

Comment: will put in some explanation soon. sorry about that

Comment: are you still sleepy? or you should have corrected this code by now

Answer (score 5):

```
void main(void)
{
    int num,i=num; // (*)
    printf("Enter a number whose prime factors are to be calculated:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    primefactor(num,i);
    getch();
}
```

What value do you think `i` will have in `(*)`?

Not sure what you want `i` to start out as, but  I'm pretty sure you **don't** want it to be something random. If you want it to start with the value of `num`, you need to assign `num` to it after you read it:

```
void main(void)
{
    int num,i; 
    printf("Enter a number whose prime factors are to be calculated:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    i = num; // assignment goes here.
    primefactor(num,i);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: i tried my best to get out of void main but this is what i am being taught :( int main() is many a times better

Comment: @fahad it *has* to be int main(void) in your case (the other case is when you have command line params)
educate your teachers with this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_(programming)#C_and_C.2B.2B

Answer (score 1):

Full recursive solution in c++ (for c replace cout lines with printf):

```
void printPrimeFactors(int num)
{
    static int divisor = 2; // 2 is the first prime number

    if ( num == 1 ) //if num = 1 we finished
    {
        divisor = 2; //restore divisor, so it'll be ready for the next run
        return;
    }
    else if ( num % divisor == 0 )  //if num divided by divisor
    {
        cout << divisor << " "; //print divisor
        printPrimeFactors( num / divisor ); //call the function with num/divisor
    }
    else //if num not divided by divisor
    {
        divisor++; //increase divisor
        printPrimeFactors( num ); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why is the `static` a must in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement prime factorization with low overhead function calls would be . . .

```
void factors(int number)
{
    int divisor = 2;
    if (number == 1) { cout << "1"; return; }
    while ((number % divisor) && (number > divisor)) divisor++;
    cout << divisor << ", ";
    factors(number / divisor);
}
```

The number of function calls (recursion) is equal to the number of prime factors, including 1.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in C. Depending on the compiler, minor changes might be needed to make in the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int primefact(int);
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter a number whose prime factors are to be calculated : \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("Prime factors of %d are : ");
    primefact(n);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
int primefact(int n)
{
    int i=2;
    while(n%i!=0)
        i++;
    printf("%d ", i);
    if(n==i)
        return 0;
    else
        primefact(n/i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with IVlad - also, what happens in the case when num is prime?  How many times will the recursive function be called for e.g. num = 7?

Comment: ...and - how does prime return it's value to the caller?

Comment: i used my concept of prime factor calculation and a prime factor program made without recursion for the help.
http://pastebin.com/fVbjFGzQ

Comment: I don't see a return statement anywhere in your prime function.

Also - try going through the code with num = 7 (and the i = num assignment in the right place) and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int ar[10]={0};
int i=0,j=2;

void P(int n)
{
    if(n<=1){
        return ;
    }

    else{
            if(n%j == 0){
                printf("%d\t",j);
                n=n/j;  

            }
            else{
                j++;                
            }   
        P(n);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter n = ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    P(n);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you don't include the corrected code, just an explanation of the error in question and the general direction on how to fix it.

Comment: There's no need to add an answer to an already properly answered question. And as @TheocharisK. said, please add also an explanation to your answer next time. And btw... Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
// recursivePrime.cpp
// Purpose: factor finding for an integer 
// Author: Ping-Sung Liao, Kaohsiung,TAIWAN
// Date: 2017/02/02
// Version : 1.0
// Reference:
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221156/recursive-func-to-find-prime-factors

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>


int primefactor(int num,int i);
int main(void)
{
    int num, i;
    printf("Enter a number whose prime factors are to be calculated:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    i=int ( sqrt (num) );
    primefactor(num,i);

    system("pause");  // instead of getch()
}

int primefactor(int num,int i)
{   printf("num %d i=%d\n", num, i);
    if (i==1)
      printf("prime found= %d\n", num);  // prime appearing in he variuable num

    else if(num%i==0)
    {   primefactor( int (num/i) , int ( sqrt(num/i) ) );
        primefactor( i , int (sqrt ( i ) ) );       
    }
    else 
    {  i--;
       primefactor(num,i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include  <`stdio.h`>

void pf(int,int);

int main()

{

int a,i=2;

     printf("Enter the Number:\n");
     scanf("%d",&a);

     pf(a,i);
}

void pf(int x,int y)

{

   if(x==1)

   return 1;

    else
    {
       if(x%y==0)
       {printf("%d\t",y);
        pf(x/y,y);
       }

       else
       {
        y++;
        pf(x,y);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need not write function to calculate next prime number. If for example, num is 24 and we continously divide it by 2 until it is no longer divisible by 2, then no other multiples of 2 can divide the number either. So ultimately only(probably) prime numbers can perfectly divide any positive integer number.

Here is my code: (I've written source code for both iterative as well as recursive logic)

```
#include<stdio.h>  
  
void pfactors_rec(int, int);  
void pfactors(int);  
  
int main()  
{  
    int num;  
  
    printf("Enter a positive integer number\n");  
    scanf("%d", &num);  
  
    printf("\nPrime Factors of %d without using recursion\n", num);  
    pfactors(num);  
  
    printf("\nPrime Factors of %d using recursion\n", num);  
    pfactors_rec(num, 2);  
  
    return 0;  
}  
  
void pfactors_rec(int num, int count)  
{  
    if(num < 1)  
        return;  
    else if(num % count == 0)  
    {  
      printf("%d\n", count);  
      pfactors_rec(num / count, count);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
      pfactors_rec(num, count+1);  
    }  
}  
  
void pfactors(int num)  
{  
    int count;  
  
    for(count = 2; (num > 1); count++)  
    {  
        while(num % count == 0)  
        {  
            printf("%d\n", count);  
            num = num / count;  
        }  
    }  
    printf("\n");  
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: Downvoting isn't _exclusively_ used to say "this answer doesn't work". It might mean "this isn't the best approach" or "this isn't a good explanation" or even "this doesn't add anything beyond the existing answers". There's a lot that goes into writing a good answer on Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, many contributors will downvote without leaving a comment, which isn't an especially clear signal as to what they were reacting to.

Comment: For what it's worth, however, for this answer I appreciate that you offer an explanation of the code, provide a functioning code example, and then provide a link for additional information. The only additional point I'd recommend is a brief explanation of why this is different from the existing answers.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know all these. I'll keep all these in mind while posting on StackOverFlow from now on.

Answer (score -1):

Implementation in java..

```
public class PrimeFactor {

public int divisor=2;
void printPrimeFactors(int num)
{

    if(num == 1)
        return;

    if(num%divisor!=0)
        {
        while(num%divisor!=0)
            ++divisor;          
        }
    if(num%divisor==0){

    System.out.println(divisor);
        printPrimeFactors(num/divisor);
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PrimeFactor obj = new PrimeFactor();
    obj.printPrimeFactors(90);
}

}
```

Comment: Beyond attempting to solve the original question, this isn't relevant to the *Turbo C* issue raised in the original question.

Comment: A quick explanation as to why this is the right way to do it would be beneficial.