# problem in prime algorithm in C

Tags: c, prime-factoring

Following the answer from @neal aise [here to get prime factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221156/recursive-func-to-find-prime-factors):
I did:

```
/*neal aise's  code*/
printPrimeFactors(int num) {
  int i;
  for (i = 2; i < sqrt(num); i=next_prime(i)) {
     if (num %i){
        printf("%d", i);
     }
  } 
}

/*my code*/
int next_prime(int p){
   int prime_found = 0; 
   while (!prime_found){
    if (p <= 1)/* if low number comes in, then */
       p = 2; /* next prime is always 2 (first prime) */
    else
          if ((p % 2) == 0) /* no even primes */
              p++;      /* make the number odd before test */
          else
              p += 2;       /* get next odd numero to test */
    prime_found = is_prime(p); /*check if number is prime*/
    }
    return (p);
}


int is_prime(int p){
    int curr_num = 2;                  /* start divisor at 2 */
    float stop_num = sqrt((float) p);  /* no divisor > sqrt of number needed */    
    while(curr_num <= stop_num){
        if ((p % curr_num) == 0)      /* not prime if evenly divisible */
            return (0);
        else
            curr_num++;              /* increment divisor */
    }
    return(1);                         /* not evenly divisible, return prime */
}
```

How do I moddify the code in function

> printPrimeFactors()

so it works as desired?

Comment: Try adding some `cout << ` statements into your code. They always helped me debug things like this.

Comment: What does your `is_prime()` function do?

Comment: can you post your code for `is_prime()`?  Also, input/output code...

Comment: First bug: `if(num%i)` will activate only when num is not divisible by i.  If you want the prime factors of num, then you should negate this, or more meaningfully change it to `if(num%i!=0)`

Comment: Edited c code, is_prime, tells if number is a prime

Comment: @Jon, added is_prime() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "prime number generator", interfaces is ok to me. But your code limit the number of prime numbers.

meaningless interfaces is not valuable. it can write more simply.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n, m;
  for (n = 1; n < 1000 /* specify your max */; n++) {
    for (m = n-1; m > 1; m--)
      if (n % m == 0) break;
    if (m == 1)
      printf("%d\n", n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: and what about the prime factors?, Dou you see the code feasible?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of logic errors:

```
if (num%i) // Change this to...
if ((num%i)==0) // num%i == 0 when i divides num, this 'i' is a prime factor.
```

Also, you will only print out roughly half of the prime factors by stopping at `<sqrt(num)`. Either change the exit condition of the for loop to be `i <= num`:

```
for (i = 2; i <= num; i=next_prime(i)) { // note the <=
  if (num %i){
     printf("%d ", i);
  }
}
```

Or the alternative, more efficient method. Note the factors will not be in order:

```
for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); i=next_prime(i)) {
  if (num %i){
     printf("%d %d ", i, num/i); // Print out the pair, since we stop at i<=sqrt(num)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of x = sqrt(n_limit) and if(n < x), you can do it like if(n*n < n_limit). No need for expensive sqrt(), floats or casts.