# Factorization in C-Recursion

Tags: c, recursion, factorization

I've been asked to write a  void function in c(no loops), that gets an even number(lets say 80), and prints it like this
2*2*5*2*2 
As you can see the result is 80 lol.
Between 2 numbers you need to print "*", and the odd number(for my example,5) you need to print it in the middle, or if there is an odd numbers of "2" in the number, lets say 96 you need to print it like that:2*2*2*3*2*2
If the given number is odd, return the number.
I whould like to get not only te answer, but the way you "think" before starting to code. 
Here is what i got so far

```
if(n%4==0)
{
  printf("2*");
  PrintTwos(n/4);
  return;
 }
 if(n%2==0)
 {
 printf("*2");
 PrintTwos(n/2);
  return;
  }
   printf("%d",n);
```

Comment: How would you do that (with pen and paper)? What do you try to code so far?

Comment: Show some code!

Comment: first of all, thinking about a stop condition. Lets say if the number is odd.But my main problem is to understand how can I print my number in a way that my odd factor(5,sorry if that not the right word for it) to appear in the middle and not in the end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recursive func to find prime factors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221156/recursive-func-to-find-prime-factors)

Comment: As far as I [can see](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39468397/2) you didn't got too far. The piece of code is not even a function!

Comment: You should start by dividing your task in this function: is it odd or not ? what is the shortest even nbr ? and then print prime factors. That make 3 task, and also 3 functions ;-)

Comment: Ho ware you going to print numer 4? Should it be `2*2` or `2*1*2`...?

Comment: If the number is 2, the output is :2*1

Comment: If you call your (incomplete) function in the [current version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39468397/3) with `n==4` it will print `2*` in the first `if()` and go recursively with `n==1`. Then it will print `1` in the last branch and return to a caller. Finally you'll get  `2*1` and I'm afraid that's _not_ what you're supposed to output for `4`.

Comment: ...and for input `8` it would print `2**21` instead of `2*2*1*2`.

Comment: @SimonPA You're wrong. The task is to extract all twos and distribute them evenly, but NOT to find any prime factors. See this part: _'the odd number (...) you need to print it in the middle'_ – just **print** the odd number, **not factorize** it. Additionally, _'If the given number is odd, return the number.'_ – again, **return** the odd number, **not factorize** it. So `168` should become `2*2*21*2` and not `2*2*3*7*2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is some pseudo code:

```
func(nbr)
  isOdd(nbr)         // recursive stop condition
    print nbr
    return

  evenNbr = findFirstEven(nbr)  //return the shortest even number from nbr
  print evenNbr
  func(nbr / evenNbr)
```

I didn't add logic for the `*` printing because i'm sure u can figure that about by yourself. And one case will break that pseudo code, but that's a good start to help you thinking about what your recursive function should do.

EDIT following comments: (NOT COMPLETE : odd number in the middle is missing in this)

```
int findFirstEven(nbr, i) {
    if (nbr%i != 0)
      return findFirstEven(nbr, i++);
    return i;
}

int primefact(int n)
{
    int i=2;
    i = findFirstEven(n, i);

    printf("%d*", i);
    if(n==i)
        printf("1");
        return 0;
    else
        primefact(n/i);
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: Can i please add the solution for this probm, and help me understand what is going on there?

Comment: Don't you want to search a little ? is it a school exercise ? If yes the goal is to think by yourself. You have almost everything here. But if you really don't want... ok...

Comment: you have to do something to find the prime number. You can't keep puting 'if' for all primes right :) Let's edit the main post together

Comment: check out my EDIT, understand it, and try it

Comment: not at all ? not even to find even numbers ? then we have to make that loop... recursive ;-)

Comment: Please note that using recursion instead of loops is always a very bad idea. As is practising recursion - if you practice it a lot you will end up using it in real applications, which is a bad idea in 99% of the cases. Recursion has very limited real-world use: a few some special cases when doing algorithm theory.

Comment: Did u managed to finish it ?
@Lundin : He is probably learning recursion right now

Comment: @SimonPA If I read your pseudo-half-code correctly, it would print something like `2 2 9` for input `36` whilst the desired result is `2*9*2`.

Comment: @CiaPan true, i didn't see the "odd in the middle" part.

Comment: @Lundin It's not _that bad_ in this case – there's very limited number of bits in a C integer, so the recursion gets no deeper than 16 levels here. Or may be 32, if one uses an environment with a 64-bit int.

Comment: @CiaPan Any case of recursion which can't get tail-call optimized is questionable at best. It's not obvious in this case and I can't bother to disassemble code from some 4 year old post. 16 levels of recursion is plain horrible on any low end platform. Some PICs halt and catch fire if you have a call depth deeper than 8 function calls, as one example.

Comment: @Lundin Well, AFAIR what I was told in my studies (long, long time ago), some CPUs allow not more than two levels of calls in microcode... And today some high-level environments may dump 50 or 100 lines of stack trace on unhandled exception. There is no single, general rule – everything depends on the environment...

Comment: @CiaPan Having lots of memory is no excuse for writing crappy code. What most people don't remember from their studies, is _why they should be using recursion_. Because it is almost dead certain that no sound rationale why was provided in the beginner C class. In the algorithm class, someone might have said that recursion should be used in various search/sort algorithms. Where the truth is that you could use recursion for cases in case you have no "parent pointer", forcing you to use stack depth to store return address, instead of explicit variables. Still a bad idea even then.

Comment: @lundin Once you use 'crap' I do EOT.

Comment: @CiaPan Can you come up with a more suitable name than 'crap' for this generated machine code disassembly then? https://godbolt.org/z/uSzjcT. Because I can't.

Comment: @SimonPA As a comment to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468397/factorization-in-c-recursion/39469163#comment66258547_39468604) I'd like to ask: did **you** manage to finish it? Because [**your** code, as it is now](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39468604/5), does **not** produce results satisfying requirements given in the question...

Answer (score 0):

You need to distribute 2's in halves, so you need to remove *two* twos from the number before the recursive step – otherwise the recursive step would have to know how deep it is to keep from printing too many twos on the left side.
Of course you must verify if there actualy are two twos!

So:

```
void PrintTwosInNumber(unsigned n)
{
    if(n % 4 == 0)
    {
        printf("2*");
        PrintTwosInNumber(n/4);
        printf("*2");
    }
    else if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("2*");
        PrintTwosInNumber(n/2);
    }
    else
        printf("%u", n);
}
```

You can save the last recursive step with

```
void PrintTwosInNumber(unsigned n)
{
    if(n % 4 == 0)
    {
        printf("2*");
        PrintTwosInNumber(n/4);
        printf("*2");
    }
    else if(n % 2 == 0)
        printf("2*%u", n/2);
    else
        printf("%u", n);
}
```

*Edit:*

Please note the function will fall into an infinite recursion for `n==0` – zero is infinitely divisible by `2`. However, zero can *not* be represented as a product of any number of 2's and some odd numer, so it is out of scope of this problem.
Anyway if it was a *real* programming task, one should take that special case into account and add a protecting `if(n==0) return;` branch, just to be on the safe side if a caller passes a wrong parameter value.

Comment: Very elegant solution!